# making authenticated api calls from gaej

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-api, google-apps

I want to access google AuditService api from google app engine application.user is already logged in to my app using `UserService` via google credentials.

Is there a way I can make authenticated calls without the need of user re authenticating my app.

```
AuditService service = new AuditService("userEmail", "password", "domain name", "application name");
```

in the above call I don't have userEmail and password,but I have the `user` object which I got using `UserService` ,when user first logged in to my application.Any way to use this `user` object to make authenticated calls ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you can do this by storing and providing an authentication token instead of the user's credentials. On the first request, proceed with the username/password authentication as normal, then generate an authorization token using [service.getAuthToken(...)](https://developers.google.com/gdata/javadoc/com/google/gdata/client/GoogleService#getAuthToken%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29). Store that token with your user model. For subsequent requests, instead of using the AuditService constructor that takes the user's credentials, use the one that omits them: [AuditService(domain, applicationName)](http://code.google.com/p/gdata-java-client/source/browse/trunk/java/src/com/google/gdata/client/appsforyourdomain/audit/AuditService.java?r=296#80). Once constructed, call [service.setUserToken(token)](https://developers.google.com/gdata/javadoc/com/google/gdata/client/GoogleService#setUserToken%28java.lang.String%29) to provide the stored token. You should then be able to make authenticated requests. Be sure to handle AuthenticationExceptions that will be raised by invalid/expired tokens.

Comment: question was abt using User object , which I get when user logs in to my app.but Seems like the User object can not give much info for authentication.So I ll have to do the Oauth Dance